# How to click on "Not Now" button within Instagram through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, instagram

I am trying to login to Instagram with an "instagram bot" that I am currently coding. I have gotten it past the login screen, past the "get the app" screen and how it want's to turn on notifications. The two option are "Turn on" and "not now". I am trying to  use the same method as before to click "not now" but it wont work. The code (using inspect element on firefox) says

```
<button class="aOOlW   HoLwm " tabindex="0">Not Now</button>
```

I have tried using the class code with

```
notNowButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='aOOlW HoLwm']")
# or
notNowButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@tabindex='0']")
```

but that doesn't work either. Any help?

the notification:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

using `WebDriverWait` and Xpath match text `Not Now`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 

notNowButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
    lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]')
)
notNowButton .click()
```

Answer (score 1):

so this somehow worked for me.i have tested it like 10 times but this is probably not the best way.

```
#we just set a simple sleep time.it's not complicated we just wait for 5 seconds to make sure the page is fully loaded
sleep(5)
#since it's a button we just write //button and then it has to search for the described class which in this scenario it is aOOlW   HoLwm and then it just clicks on it
not_now_notif=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='aOOlW   HoLwm ']")

not_now_notif.click()
```

btw you can check here.i do believe this might be helpful too
https://www.edureka.co/community/575/need-wait-until-page-completely-loaded-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were pretty close.

In you first code trial:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='aOOlW HoLwm']")
```

The `<tag>` is not `<a>` tag but **`<button>`** tag. So changing it as following would have worked.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='aOOlW   HoLwm ']")
```

Now the desired element is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and the following line would have worked perfecto:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='aOOlW   HoLwm ']"))).click()
```

As an alternative you could have also used *cssSelector* as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.aOOlW.HoLwm"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/username/Documents/WebDriver/chromedriver')


browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Not Now')]")[0].click()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but explain what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question

Answer (score 0):

You must first use copy css selector to Copy the path

```
Notnow = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > div.RnEpo.Yx5HN > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm")

Notnow.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, find the element by its text and assign it to `not_now_button`:

```
not_now_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Not Now']")
```

Then click the button:

```
not_now_button.click()
```